# Tree, node with value just greater than a given n

Tags: tree

Given a tree and a number n. Find next larger element in the Tree i.e find a node with value just greater than n ? I am trying to find a `recursive solution` to it...

Here's the tree

```
           1
        /  |  \
      2   5   3
     /
    4
```

> So, if the value of n=2 then the answer should be 3 because it is just larger than 2.

Here's the code ... but it is returning incorrect answer , some random value is getting displayed on the console

```
 public static int nextLargest(TreeNode<Integer> root, int n){

    if(root==null)
        return 0;

    int nextlargest= Integer.MAX_VALUE;

    for(TreeNode<Integer> child:root.children){
        int childAns= nextLargest(child, n);            


    if(childAns > n && childAns < nextlargest)
            nextlargest=childAns; 

    }

        return nextlargest;

}
```

Comment: Given your homework, find all you have already tried and add it to your question.

Comment: I am trying but not getting anywhere....

Answer (score 0):

So, I was missing a condition which is

```
 if(root.data>n && root.data < nextlargest)
        return root.data;
```

So after adding it the code becomes...

```
public static int nextLargest(TreeNode<Integer> root, int n){

if(root==null)
    return 0;

int nextlargest= Integer.MAX_VALUE;

for(TreeNode<Integer> child:root.children){
    int childAns= nextLargest(child, n);            


if(childAns > n && childAns < nextlargest)
        nextlargest=childAns; 

}

if(root.data>n && root.data < nextlargest)
        return root.data;

    return nextlargest;

}
```